# What is the name of the Load event in Chrome DevTools protocol?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know which of the events output by [chrome.Tracing](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Tracing/) corresponds to the main loadEventFired event? Is there a reference for the events anywhere? I'd also like to work out how to extract the timestamp in seconds

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `loadEventEnd`.

The `blink.user_timing` tracing category needs to be enabled for this to be generated.

Discovered after perusing source of the excellent [Lighthouse](http://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/7d12091a79a428bd0d82549090e0084df67334d6/lighthouse-core/gather/computed/trace-of-tab.js) project